# Spring integration : control ActiveMQ connection

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, integration

I am looking for controlling ActiveMQ connections after starting of application in cluster environment if I want to disconnect some slave machine through code.
Any help around this will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Spring has any direct integration with ActiveMQ. Spring offers JMS integration which, of course, uses the generic JMS API which every JMS provider implements.

To manage ActiveMQ from a remote application will you need to use something like JMX.